# How do I alter this "Zip multiple files" script (mac os) to remove the extension from the output?

Tags: macos, bash, zip

I use this script to zip multiple files into individual zip files (though an automator service, so Bash)

```
for f in "$@"
do
zip -j "$f.zip" "$f"
done
```

it works perfectly BUT, the zip file has the extension in the name:

zipme.jpg comes out as zipme.jpg.zip

the result I am after is : zipme.zip

it would be even better if you could leave the extension and replace the period with an underscore:  zipme_jpg.zip

Many of my clients have problems with the two periods. Right now I remove them by hand after zipping. Can anyone tell me how to fix the script?

Comment: Begs the question… what do you gain from zipping a jpg? A jpg is pretty much an incompressible format… you'd be better off just making lower quality jpgs

Comment: @Tetsujin Minor (I must agree, this is extremely minor) amounts of compression (maybe less than the zip file's overhead) is just one possible reason to Zip.  Also, an archive that stores metadata, such as the original file's timestamp.  Then the original (compressed) file's timestamp is preserved even if some action, like transferring a file over some networking protocols, updates the timestamp of the (archive) file that gets copied.  I've had a program not perform a task because of a data file's timestamp, so such details can actually matter.

Comment: @TOOGAM - tbh, you may be right… but that would raise my next question… why individually, why not as a group? It all smacks too much of [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info) to really garner my interest ;)

Comment: in my particular case my clients sometimes have trouble with larger files (movies and such) so they ASK for me to post separately. And if I just post a picture or movie on the ftp they often have trouble figuring out how to download rather than just having their browser pop up and view (my clients are often simple folks, not even using an ftp client). But a link to a zip file never fails (and I don't have to play tech support).

Comment: @TerryWayneRanson - ah, OK, makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Jpegs are already compressed, there's no need to compress them again with zip. But you could use substring removal in parameter expansion to remove the extension.

```
for f in "$@"
do
zip -j "${f%.*}.zip" "$f"
done
```

The `${f%.*}` strips the extension off the file name.

Comment: Much simpler than the sed or redirection methods I'd have suggested. Nice.

Comment: yes, that was actually just an example filename. Thank you for your help. The code works perfectly.